# @@History/@@scroll|# Cookie

Tags: wordpress, cookies

In the process of getting GDPR compliant, I've found a number of cookies on legacy sites that no one on the internet seems to have any information on.

One that I've seen multiple times is called "@@History/@@scroll|#". I have no idea what to declare the purpose of this cookie as. I would assume, just by the name, that it tracks either user activity on the site, scrolling habits, or previous browsing history. These are just guesses though.

Is this cookie from WordPress? A plugin? Something else? Anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 1):

It has as source: youtube.com
Initiator: Webserver

I have it come with a YouTube script.

Answer (score 0):

For my site it show `@@History/@@scroll` for PDF viewer i am using on website to view PDF files, It also show Youtube.com but i am not sure if it is Youtube as it doesnt this cookie on other website so my best guess is

It is used by PDF viewer such as PDF.js `https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/`
This stored Scroll position, zoom level etc for this plugin